# Adding AutoCorrect to Custom IME

Tags: android, keyboard, ime, autocorrect

I've developed a custom IME for Android from the ground up. The problem is I don't know where to start implementing AutoCorrection. Are there pre-built dictionaries within Android? Is there an API specific for autocorrection, or is it just a matter of importing your own dictionary and checking words against it?